# Solve Navigation bar and overlay

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

In my first viewController I have hidden the navigation bar with the following code.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
}
```

but when I go to other viewcontroler and want to go back sliding from left to right (swipe), it is seen as overlapping

I attach an image for more details:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
}
```

To this:

```
var firstEntrance = true

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    if firstEntrance {
         self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    } else {
         firstEntrance = false
         self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! It worked
Although with `var firstEntrance = false`

Thank you